# How to identify a window playing a video in a browser

Tags: windows, video, browser, youtube, spy++

I wish to understand how one can programmatically identify if a window is playing video content?
I used spy++ to identify particular attributes for windows playing video but I did not find any particular attributes associated with window playing video.
I have handles to all windows on screen and want to find which ones are playing video ? Could you please throw some light on how can one do this and are there any special properties associated with a window playing video?

I found similar article :
[can we get window handle of the window which is playing video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882653/can-we-get-window-handle-of-the-window-which-is-playing-video)
But I don't want to minimize application , I know user is using browser(ie,firefix,chrome) to watch video (from youtube,hulu)and window is visible on screen.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that a video-playing window will have any special attributes. Why should it? There's no `WS_VIDEOPLAYER` style.

Comment: ohh.. Thanks Code Gray. Then is there any way to identify which window is playing video by any other means?

Comment: [The answer to the question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5883099/366904) already explains why this is not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we get window handle of the window which is playing video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882653/can-we-get-window-handle-of-the-window-which-is-playing-video)

Answer (score 0):

You can if you have execution privileges over the environment the Flash Player is executed in. You can listen for the playing event thrown by the Flash Player.

[Listen for my Flash event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187941/listen-for-my-flash-event-in-javascript)